# Unable to update other schema table in trigger

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I want to update other schema table via trigger. when i am creating the trigger from scott schema its working fine, but in system schema getting the following error.

```
Error(3,14): PL/SQL: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

create or replace trigger trig_tt_1
after update on system.table1
begin

update scott.table1 a
set (a.col3,a.col4,a.col5) = (select b.col3,b.col4,b.col5 
                                  from system.table1 b 
                                  where b.col1= a.col1);

end;

for information, when i execute the update script alone its working fine.
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing `GRANT` on the object you are trying to access from different schema.

Try this :

1.Login to `SCOTT` schema.

2.Give `GRANT ALL on scott.table1 to SYSTEM`.

3.Login to `SYSTEM` schema and create trigger again.

> Tested :

**Without grants - Error encountered**

[image: image 1]

**Provided grants**

[image: Image 2]

**Trigger created without errors**

[image: Image 3]

Comment: This is not a table access issue. If table access occurs then the error message would have been " Table or object not found". This is due to insufficient priv to create TRIGGER in other schema

Comment: Give it a try yourself and you would agree with me.

Answer (score 0):

This error only occurs when you do not have CREATE ANY TRIGGER priv. As you have created TRIGGER in SCOTT schema successfully but while trying to create TRIGGER in SYSTEM schema you are facing " INSUFFICIENT PRIV" error.
There are two possible ways to resolve this issue.

**Recommended**

1. Login to SYSTEM schema and then try to CREATE trigger. Here in this case you are trying to create the trigger from SCOTT Schema.

**No Recommended**

2. `GRANT CREATE ANY TRIGGER TO SCOTT` --> This will enable you to create TRIGGER in any schema. But this highly not recommended. These rights should remain with DBA's only and not with developers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The user could successfully create `trigger` in `SCOTT` schema and not able to create in `SYSTEM` schema